# giving a reference to a function in another module in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, perl-module, tk-toolkit

I want to make a small GUI using Tk in Perl that will have 2 buttons: <kbd>Race</kbd> and <kbd>Quit</kbd>.

I want the <kbd>Race</kbd> button to run a function that is located in a module `Car` and is called `Race`.

I've written the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Car;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->Label(-text => "The Amazing Race")->pack;
$mw->Button(
        -text    => 'Race',
        -command => sub {Car->Race()},
)->pack;
$mw->Button(
        -text    => 'Quit',
        -command => sub { exit },
)->pack;
MainLoop;
```

It works, but It seems stupid to me to make an unnamed subroutine that will just call another subroutine. But when I tried to use `-command => sub Car->Race(),` or `-command => sub \&Car->Race(),` it didn't work.

I understand that this is because I'm not passing a reference to the function. How do I pass a reference to a function that is located in another namespace (module)?

Comment: Try `-command => sub { goto Car->Race(); },` See `perldoc -f goto` for details.

Comment: @shawnhcorey => that will attempt to goto the label with the same name as the stringified return value of `Car->Race()`.  The correct usage with `goto` would be something like `sub {@_ = 'Car'; goto &{Car->can('Race')}}`.  But in this case, using goto is just tedious and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is symple:

```
$mw->Button(
        -text    => 'Race',
        -command => \&Car::Race,
)->pack;
```

But if you need to pass any special arguments to that functions or call it as method, you still need an anon sub:

```
$mw->Button(
        -text    => 'Race',
        -command => sub { Car->Race(@_) },
)->pack;
```

This one calls Race as method of package Car and pass all arguments to it.

Comment: `\&Car::Race` is not equivalent to `sub {Car->Race()}`, and modules are typically loaded using `use`, not `require`.

Comment: I've loaded the entire `Car` module, using `use 'Car'

Comment: @ikegami I mentioned both call as function and call as method depending on what you need to call. require and use are different, but use is actually just `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import() };` as perldoc says
@Illya Melamed, yes, my fault. Fixed, thanks

Comment: Calling it a closure isn't very accurate since it doesn't close over anything. I'll fix that.

Comment: Finally, it's incorrect that you need an anon sub or a closure. Tk does provide a means of specifying arguments to pass to the callback.

Comment: You may have mentioned it, but it's very unclear that `\&Car::Race` is wrong.

Comment: I don't know why you're showing me that `use` is not the same as `require`. I know that, which is why I said what I said.

Comment: @ikegami, I actually can't say that `\&Car::Race` is wrong, because Ilya asked for a way to "the button to run a function that is located in a module Car and is called Race". Code I provided does exactly what Ilya asked for. I explained some aspects related to calling sub as method of package that might be useful to Ilya.
I agree, that your answer covers more aspects and provides more information about Tk. However I don't understand why you are so aggressive (or it's just in my mind?). I apologize if something in my words offended you.

Comment: @yko, Except he showed that Race is a method. Not being aggressive; I just kept finding problems. At first, I thought it was just a little thing that could be fixed, but it turned out that starting a new node was the way to address them, so I did.

Answer (score 7):

```
Car->Race()
```

is the same* as

```
Car->can('Race')->('Car');
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^
sub ref            args
```

As you can see, an argument is passed to the sub. If you don't want to use an anon sub, you'll have to instruct Tk to pass that argument. Tk does have a means of doing that.

```
-command => [ Car->can('Race'), 'Car' ],
```

This may or may not be a little faster, but it's definitely not as clear as

```
-command => sub { Car->Race() },
```

As for subroutines in other packages? If you have something that's called using

```
Car::Race();
```

it would be called using

```
-command => \&Car::Race,
```

But that's not what you have here.

* — Except for modules using `AUTOLOAD`. This is why autoloaders should override `can`.